# Python pandas df: if col_A contains a string from a list, append the string to col_B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of about 60 words and a data frame of over 7000 sentences. I would like to add a column for each line that contains a word from the list (some have multiple words from the list and some repeat words). I've tried a bunch of ways to no avail. Starting off with

```python
list=['a', 'b', 'c', ...]
    
   for x in list:
       if df["col_A].str.contains(x):
          df[col_B].append(x)
```

but it returns an error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

any help on how to fix this or possibly other ways to approach this would be much appreciated. New to stackoverflow and a only been coding for a few months if that helps gauge where I am at in terms of knowlage.

**Edit**: id like the new column to be of the words from the list that appear within the string from the existing one.

Also if it helps:its a movie script im trying to analyze where each row is a line from the script and who said it. I want to analyze how many times a word is said and who had favorite words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
list_words=["a",....]
def add_list_words(sentences):
 returned_list=[]
 for word in list_words:
   if word in sentences:
     returned_list.append(word)
 return list(set(returned_list)) # the set use to drop duplicate
df["col_B"]=df["col_A"].apply(add_list_words)
```